# Mapbox compositing operations in the client

Tags: mapbox

In Mapbox it looks like compositing operations cannot be done on the client side. Typically, I want to change the color map of a raster layer over a polygon, e.g. by multiplying the raster values (say it's a single band raster) by a constant. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible: we've considered writing something semi-general that does raster operations, but CORS support for image data - the hard technical requirement - doesn't have perfect browser support, and the way to do this in 2D Canvas is relatively slow.

I've implemented this quite a few times as a one-off with Leaflet - you can request the image data behind the scenes, do `getImageData` on a Canvas, do your math in a fast loop, and then write back to the canvas.

This is a [planned feature for Mapbox GL](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/193) - we hope to land it in 0.9. It's a big technical lift.